# Why is random sampling with replacement called "bootstrapping"?

Tags: statistics, terminology, bootstrap-sampling

What is the logic behind naming random sampling with replacement "[bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics))" in statistics?

Comment: You attempt to estimate information about the sampling distribution by resampling from the original sample rather than from the population, metaphorically akin to the (physically impossible) task of lifting yourself into the air by pulling up the straps on your boots

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from "An Introduction to the Bootstrap", Efron and Tibshirani, 1993.

> The bootstrap is a data-based simulation method for statistical inference, which can be used to produce inferences like (1.2) and (1.5). The use of the term bootstrap derives from the phrase *to pull oneself up by one's bootstrap*, widely thought to be based on one of the eighteenth century Adventures of Baron Munchausen, by Rudolph Erich Raspe. (The Baron had fallen to the bottom of a deep lake. Just when it looked like all was lost, he thought to pick himself up by his own bootstraps.) It is not the same as the term "bootstrap" used in computer science meaning to "boot" a computer from a set of core instructions, though the derivation is similar.

Not all sampling with replacement is called bootstrapping and there are more complicated forms of bootstrapping that involve additional selection or processing of the sample.